# What type of object can be used in a fetch for petapoco?

Tags: c#, petapoco

I have a peta poco query that returns two columns, what kind of object can I use in the fetch?

```
var data = _db.Fetch<???????>("SELECT ItemId, Sort FROM CollectionItems WHERE CollectionId in (@0)", ids);
```

the main problem is that if I try Fetch I get an exception that says

"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in TpCrm.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Couldn't find split point between System.Int32 and System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]"

the second column can be null values!!!

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic for sure:

```
dynamic data = _db.Fetch<object>("SELECT ItemId, Sort FROM CollectionItems WHERE CollectionId in (@0)", ids);
```

Then:

```
data.ItemId ... 
data.Sort ...
```

Comment: I also have some common POCO objects defined (like IDNamePair, etc) to have better intellisense and to pass to object around with static typing.